# How do I import third-party module in declaration file(*.d.ts)?

Tags: typescript, declaration-files

I created the type declaration file(`index.d.ts`), and I need to use an object of the third-party package('moment.js' in `node_modules`) as type.

```
  // index.d.ts

  import * as Moment from 'moment';

  declare var $: any;
  declare var google: any;

  interface foo {
    a: Moment;
    b: string;
    ...
  }
```

I made a code like above, but it doesn't work. How do I import a third-party module in `*.d.ts` file?

Comment: Here you go; https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/triple-slash-directives.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [.d.ts file that ships with Moment](https://github.com/moment/moment/blob/develop/moment.d.ts) wraps wraps everything it exports into a namespace. So for this lib, importing like `import * as Moment from 'moment';` means the `Moment` variable is a namespace not the interface for a Moment instance itself. What you want is the interface that lives inside the namespace.

You have two options to handle this:

```
  import * as moment from 'moment';

  interface foo {
    a: moment.Moment;
    b: string;
  }
```

Or deconstruct the interface during the import:

```
  import { Moment } from 'moment';

  interface foo {
    a: Moment;
    b: string;
  }
```

Personally, I use the first style for files of mine that use lots exported members from the namespace, but if I only need a few I use the second style.

**edit...**

If your tsconfig has `esModuleInterop` enabled (which is the newish preferred setting), the import from first example can/should remove the `* as` bit.

```
import moment from 'moment';
```